# How to render elements depends on select value in react

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

i'm newbie in react and i wanted to render different HTML Elements depends on Selected value 
And if its possible POST datas in selected html to django model

here is my react js code :

```js
class Resepy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected : 'default'
    };
  }

  setSelected = (event) => {
      let select = document.getElementById("id_field1");
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = select.value;
  }

  render() { 
       return (
            <div className="Resepy">
             <h1>Something</h1>
             <form>
              <select id="id_field1" name="field1" onChange={this.setSelected}>
                  <option value="default">Food type not selected</option>
                  <option value="burger">Burger</option>
                  <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
                  </select>
                <div id="test"></div>
                  <div className="food">{
                   this.state.selected == "default" ? 
                       <div className="default">Default</div>
                       : this.state.selected == "Burger" ?
                        <div className="burger">Burger</div>
                         : <div className="pizza">Pizza</div>
                  }</div>
                  <button type="submit">Add to tray</button>
                  </form>
             </div>
        );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are manipulating the DOM directly with react? That's a big NO.

Comment: What should i do for this?

Comment: Solution please

Comment: @Alirezatafhim check this solution which is in react https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579898/6544460...if you want to post data to backend call api in handleSubmit function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Resepy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected : ''
    };
  }

  setSelected = (event) => {
    this.setState({selected: event.target.value})
  }
  handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.state.selected)
  }

  render() { 
       return (
            <div className="Resepy">
             <h1>Something</h1>
             <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <select id="id_field1" name="field1" 
                onChange={this.setSelected} value={this.state.selected}>
                  <option value="">Food type not selected</option>
                  <option value="burger">Burger</option>
                  <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
                  </select>
                  <h3>{this.state.selected}</h3>
                  <div className="food">
                   {this.state.selected === "" ? 
                    <div className="default"></div>
                    : this.state.selected === "Burger" ?
                     <div className="burger">Burger</div>
                    :<div className="pizza">Pizza</div>
                    }
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit">Add to tray</button>
                  </form>
             </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: @vahid_akhtar onSubmit Works well ty!, and can u please check edit? i need another code too! :)

Comment: @Alirezatafhim check this and let me know is that you want?

Comment: yes, something like this , but for example when user clicks on burger, it displays the burger specefic HTML element ... and pizza or other stuffs should render like this... sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: @Alirezatafhim you want to show selected item at a time right?

Comment: yes something like that, i need that when users click on selected option displays selected food in ``` food div ``` for them ... u got what i mean?

Comment: @Alirezatafhim that's what it is doing when you select particular item then only it's showing.

Comment: it doesn't show specific HTML markup for each selection

Comment: can we chat in discord or Whatsapp or sth?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read react documentation. And javascript documentation.

Your setSelected should be like this:

```
  setSelected = event => {
      this.setState({ selected: event.target.value });
  }
```